# Why isalpha, isdigit, isspace function get float types?

Tags: c++, std

If declaration is

```
int isdigit ( int c );
```

and they is not overload?
Surely they work incorrect. But why there is implicit type conversation?

I think they should be error, as it function can only get char, or char code (int), but not others types.
Why C++ convert double to int, ever it not possible without lose precision.

C++ is strong typing language.

Comment: Are you asking why the argument is not `char`? If yes, think about Unicode.

Comment: Please, read the reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit

Comment: Are you asking why there are no additional overloads `int isdigit(float) = delete;` ?

Comment: @Cristik: the `<cctype>` functions do **not** support Unicode code points, except the ASCII subset (on systems where the corresponding codes happen to be ASCII rather than, e.g., EBCDIC). The reason `int` is used is to also support EOF.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Whether supporting EOF is the reason or being able to is just a nice accidental benefit is unclear. But yes, they definitely do not support Unicode.

Comment: It's a general property of C++, not restricted to any particular function or set of functions. A floating point value is implicitly convertible to any integral type in most contexts. It is unfortunate but the language was designed this way in the dawn of times when such things were considered cool, and it's too late to change it now. A good compiler should be able to warn you about such conversions so enable all warnings and act on every warning produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that these functions were part of C before being ported to C++ verbatim. A more instructive answer can therefore be given with reference to C.

The "End Of File" indicator (`EOF`) is defined by the C standard to not clash with any 8 bit `char`, so it needs a wider type than that and an `int` will suffice. And most of the character-type functions are designed to work with `EOF` as an input.

Furthermore all single quotation character literals like `'a'`, `'b'`, etc. are `int` types in C. (Although they are `char` types in C++).

So `isdigit` &c. take an `int` as a parameter. They return an `int` since that's the native conditional type in C. (Note that in C++, the conditional operators return `bool`, but in C they return `int`.)

Any overloads (function overloads of course are not part of C) for floating point parameters would be pointless since character encoding is always done with integral types.

Comment: I'm interesting why there implicit type conversation between double and int.